# Visualization using ggplot2 (draw curves) with a big dataset

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization, bigdata

I want to use `ggplot2` to draw curves (`geom_curve` with `ggplot2 2.0.0`), but the number of curves is too large (about 2 million curves). I want to draw them in one figure, but it will take too long.

I want to get a figure like this:

[image: the facebook links]

How I can draw a figure like this? `ggplot2`? or any other better tools?

Comment: Even as your link shown, you don't need draw all of them, sampling. People can't distinguish million of curves in a picture.

Comment: See an example here: http://flowingdata.com/2011/05/11/how-to-map-connections-with-great-circles/

Comment: Similar concept here: http://toddwschneider.com/posts/analyzing-1-1-billion-nyc-taxi-and-uber-trips-with-a-vengeance/